# KNN with tips dataset

Tags: python, pandas, knn, valueerror

I'm trying to apply the `KNN` to the `tips dataset` and I mapped the objects as follows:

```
f.Male=df.Gender.map({'Female':0,'Male':1})
df.Smokes = df.Smoker.map({'No': 0, 'Yes': 1})
df.Dinner = df.Time.map({'Lunch': 0, 'Dinner': 1})
df.Day_w = df.Day.map({'Sun': 0, 'Mon': 1, 'Tue' : 2, 'Wed' : 3, 'Thu' : 4, 'Fri': 5, 'Sat': 6 })
```

My inputs and outputs are,

```
inputs = df[['Bill', 'Party', 'Gender', 'Time']]
outputs = df['Tip']

knn = nei.KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=4)
```

Works but when I call

```
knn.fit(inputs, outputs)
```

I get

```
   ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Female'
```

Any advice is welcome

Comment: your first line is `f.Male`  shouldnt it be `df.Male....` ?

Answer (score 1):

The value error says, that the input values contain the string "female" (check your dataframe, if the values are really all numeric).

I woud expect that your column mapping for column "Gender" didn't work. In the code you assigned to mapping of the "Gender" column to the "Male" column (not "Gender" column), try to change the first line of your code to:

```
df.Gender=df.Gender.map({'Female':0,'Male':1})
```

And check that the values in the variables "inputs" and "outputs" are all numeric.

Answer (score 1):

In your prepping, you map the data of the ‘Time’ column to ‘Dinner’ and ‘Gender’ to ‘Male’. In selecting the inputs, you don’t use the newly created columns but the original ones. Try changing that!